# How to write a simple test code to test a python program that has a function with two arguments?

Tags: python-3.x, file, testing

I'm new in python, I have written a python program that reads **a list of files** and saves the total number of a **particular character (ch)** in a **dictionary** and then returns it.

The program works fine, now I'm trying to write a simple test code to test the program.

I tried with the following code,

```
def test_read_files():
    assert read_files("H:\\SomeTextFiles\\zero-k.txt", 'k') == 0, "Should be 0"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_read_files()
    print("Everything passed")
```

I named the program as ***test_read_files.py***

My python code is as follows:

```
# This function reads a list of files and saves number of
# a particular character (ch) in dictionary and returns it.

def read_files(filePaths, ch):

    # dictionary for saing no of character's in each file
    dictionary = {}
    
    for filePath in filePaths:

        try:
            # using "with statement" with open() function
            with open(filePath, "r") as file_object:
                # read file content
                fileContent = file_object.read()
                dictionary[filePath] = fileContent.count(ch)
            
        except Exception:
            # handling exception
            print('An Error with opening the file '+filePath)
            dictionary[filePath] = -1

    return dictionary


fileLists = ["H:\\SomeTextFiles\\16.txt", "H:\\SomeTextFiles\\Statement1.txt",
             "H:\\SomeTextFiles\\zero-k.txt", "H:\\SomeTextFiles"]

print(read_files(fileLists, 'k'))
```

I named it as ***read_files.py***

When I run the test code, getting an error: **NameError: name 'read_files' is not defined**

The program and the test code all are in the same folder (different than the python folder though).

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I am understanding this correctly, but if both of you python files:

1. test_read_files.py
2. read_files.py

Are in the same directory.. Then you should be able to just add at the top of the **test_read_files.py** the following import command:

```
from read_files import read_files
```

This will import the read_files function from your **read_files.py** script and that way you will be able to run it inside the other file.

Comment: It solved the previous error but seems it runs with the parameters that were defined in the python program, but I want to run the test code with only the parameters in the test code. I had to delete some lines.

{'H:\\SomeTextFiles\\16.txt': 581, 'H:\\SomeTextFiles\\Statement1.txt': 0, 'H:\\SomeTextFiles\\zero-k.txt': 0, 'H:\\SomeTextFiles': -1}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
  File "C:/Python scripts/test_read_files.py", line 3, in test_read_files
    assert read_files(["H:\\SomeTextFiles\\zero-k.txt"], 'k') == 0, "Should be 0"
AssertionError: Should be 0 @MiTriPy

Comment: I solved that, Thanks.

Comment: I notice now there are some logical errors in the original code. For example the loop (for filePath in filePaths:) loops over all the individual chars in the string you are passing to read_files. I think your intention was to go over multiple files ? 
Let me know if I can help further

Comment: Please let me know about those logical errors. The code was intended to read a list of files that what I did. @MiTriPy

Comment: @abhimanyue late response but see how in the read_files.py you are passing a list ([]) to the read_files() function? 
Well the same function is used in your test case as well, but instead of a list you are passing a string (""). This is causing the loop that grabs each file in the list to grab each char in the string.
Doing something like this in the test file should help:
`read_files(["H:\\SomeTextFiles\\zero-k.txt"], 'k')` (notice the addition of [])